# data table template as prop vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a component that I use in various parts of my application to render tables.

What I want to do now in view of the fact that every time I need to add more custom fields to the table (templates), is to be able to pass these templates as a prop to the parent component so that I do not have to always be editing this component.

As you can see I have tried in many ways and I have not been able to find the solution.

**Father component**

```
      <template>
        <section>
          <data-table-search
            :titleFilter="titleFilter"
            :selectFilter="selectFilter"
            :srchfunction="srchfunction"
            :clkfunction="clkfunction"
            :filterable="filterable"
            :itemsFilter="itemsFilter"
            :clickSelect="clickSelect"
            :btnew="btnew"
            :elevationNew="elevationNew"
            :btnNewClass="btnNewClass"
            :btsmall="btsmall">
          </data-table-search>
            <div :is="processedHtml"></div>
          <v-data-table
            class="tableBackground"
            :dense="dense"
            :headers="headers"
            :items="items.data"
            :server-items-length="items.recordsFiltered"
            :options.sync="options"
            :loading="loading"
            :footer-props="footerProps"
            no-data-text="No hay datos disponibles"
            :loading-text="$t('comunes.general.cargando')">
            <template v-slot:progress>
              <v-progress-linear
                height="2"
                :color="colorProgress"
                indeterminate
              ></v-progress-linear>
            </template>
                  <template v-if="Object.keys(spanState).length > 0 && spanState.state == true" v-slot:item.state="{ item }">
                      <div class="">
                      <span v-if="item.state === 1" color="red">Abierto</span>
                      <span v-else-if="item.state === 2" color="green">En bodega</span>
                      <span v-else-if="item.state === 3" color="green">Revisado</span>
                      <span v-else-if="item.state === 4" color="green">En correo</span>
                      <span v-else-if="item.state === 5" color="green">Aceptada</span>
                      <span v-else-if="item.state === 6" color="green">Parcial</span>
                      <span v-else-if="item.state === 7" color="green">Rechazada</span>
                      <span v-else-if="item.state === 8" color="green">Orden de trabajo</span>
                      <span v-else-if="item.state === 9" color="green">Incompleto</span>
                      <span v-else-if="item.state === 10" color="green">Facturado</span>
                      <span v-else color="green"></span>
                    </div>
                    </template>
            <template v-slot:item.activo="{ item }">
              <v-icon :small="btsmall" color="green" v-if="item.activo">check_circle</v-icon>
              <v-icon :small="btsmall" color="red" v-else>cancel</v-icon>
            </template>
            <template v-if="actions.length>1" v-slot:item.opciones="{ item }">
              <v-menu  offset-y small>
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                  <v-btn :small="btsmall" class="btn-opciones" dark v-on="on">{{ $t('comunes.general.opciones') }}</v-btn>
                </template>
                <v-list class="dt-actions">
                  <v-list-item-group v-for="(action, index) in actions" :key="index">
                    <v-list-item @click="_onClick(action.action, item.id)">
                      <v-list-item-icon :class="action.color">
                        <v-icon :small="btsmall" class="text-white" v-text="action.icon"></v-icon>
                      </v-list-item-icon>
                      <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title v-text="action.text"></v-list-item-title>
                      </v-list-item-content>
                    </v-list-item>
                  </v-list-item-group>
                </v-list>
              </v-menu>
            </template>
            <template v-else v-slot:item.opciones="{ item }">
            <v-btn :small="btsmall" class="btn-opciones"  @click="_onClick(actions[0].action, item.id)" dark v-on="on">{{ btnSeleccionar ? btnSeleccionar : $t('comunes.general.seleccionar') }}</v-btn>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
        </section>
      </template>

      <script>
      import datatableMixin from '@/mixins/datatable'
      import dataTableSearch from '@/components/utilidades/dataTableSearch'

      export default {
        name: 'datatable',
        mixins: [ datatableMixin ],
        components: { dataTableSearch },
        data () {
          return {
            on: false,
            template: '<h1>Hola</h1>'
          }
        },
        props: {
          searchFunction: Function,
          clkfunction: Function,
          clickSelect: Function,
          endpoint: String,
          dense: Boolean,
          btsmall: Boolean,
          // initialData: {
          //   type: Boolean,
          //   default: true
          // },
          re: Function,
          initialData: {
            type: Boolean,
            default () {
              return true
            }
          },
          headers: {
            type: Array,
            default: { }
          },
          spanState: {
            type: Object,
            default () {
              return {}
            }
          },
          itemsFilter: {
            type: Array,
            default: Array
          },
          templates: {},
          filterable: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
          },
          selectFilter: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
          },
          titleFilter: {
            type: String,
            default: 'Filtro'
          },
          btnew: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
          },
          btnActionClass: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
          },
          btnNewClass: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
          },
          elevationAction: {
            type: Number,
            default: 2
          },
          elevationNew: {
            type: Number,
            default: 2
          },
          colorProgress: {
            type: String,
            default: 'primary'
          },
          btnSeleccionar: {
            type: String,
            default: null
          },
          actions: Array,
          endManual: Boolean
        },
        computed: {
          processedHtml () {
            // let html = this.html.replace('[Placeholder]', '<my-component></my-component>')
            return {
              template: this.template
            }
          }
        },
        mounted () {
          this.getData()
          if (Object.keys(this.spanState).length > 0) {
            console.log('fds', this.items)
          }
        },
        methods: {
          _onClick (event, id) {
            this.clkfunction(event, id)
          },
          async srchfunction (text) {
            this.search = text
            this.options.page = 1
            this.getData()
          }
        }
      }
      </script>
```

**Child component**:

```
      <template>
        <div>
          <v-dialog v-if="dialogModalBuscador" v-model="dialogModalBuscador" scrollable max-width="600px">
            <v-card>
              <v-card-title>
                <span class="h2" >{{title}}</span>
              </v-card-title>
              <v-card-text class="pb-0">
                <data-table
                  :btsmall="true"
                  :endpoint="endpoint"
                  :headers="headers"
                  :filterable="true"
                  :actions="actions"
                  :clkfunction="clickFunction"
                  :initialData="initialDataL"
                  v-on:changeInitialDatastateEmit="emm"
                  :showCountOrdenesTecnico="True"
                  :customTemplate="re"
                  :endManual="true">

                  <template
              v-for="header in headers"
              v-slot:[`item.${header.value}`]="{ item }"
            >
              <slot :name="[`item.${header.value}`]" :item="item">
                {{ getVal(item, header.value) }}
              </slot>
            </template>

              <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <span v-if="item.countOrdenNoFacturada === 0" color="red">Sin Entregar</span>
                      <span v-else-if="item.countOrdenNoFacturada === 2" color="green">Solicitado</span>
                      <span v-else color="green"></span>
                    </div>
                  </template>
                </data-table>

              </v-card-text>
              <v-card-actions class="d-block" >
                <v-btn color="red" @click="dialogModalBuscador = false" outlined  >{{$t('comunes.general.cancelar')}}</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
        </div>
      </template>

      <script>
      import configMixin from '@/mixins/config'
      import dataTable from '@/components/utilidades/dataTable'
      export default {
        mixins: [ configMixin ],
        components: { dataTable },
        data () {
          return {
            dialogModalBuscador: false,
            loading: false,
            initialDataL: this.initialData
            // templates: `1.0/cda/serviciosproductosobtener/${id}/`
          }
        },
        props: {
          title: {
            type: String,
            default: 'Listado default'
          },
          endpoint: {
            type: String,
            default: {}
          },
          headers: {
            type: Array
          },
          hidden: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true
          },
          initialData: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true
          },
          actions: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => [ { 'text': 'Seleccionar', 'icon': 'check_box', 'action': 'ver', 'color': 'primary' } ]
          }
          // endpoint: String
        },
        mounted () {
        },
        methods: {
          re () {
            return { template: `<template v-slot:item.countOrdenNoFacturada="{ item }">
            <div class="">
                      <span v-if="item.countOrdenNoFacturada === 0" color="red">Abiertoooo</span>
                      <span v-else color="green"></span>
                    </div>
            </template>      
            ` }
          },
          async clickFunction (event, id) {
            if (event === 'ver') this.$emit('getId', id)
            if (event === 'editar') this.$router.push({ name: this.openRoute(`cda/formulario/${id}/`) })
            if (event === 'crear') this.$router.push({ name: this.openRoute(`cda/formulario/${id}/`) })
          },
          emm (e) {
            console.log('EMMIT', e)
            this.initialDataL = e
          }
        }
      }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `v-bind="$attrs"`. which means that all the attributed passed to the parent component will pass on to the child component.

so in your case use it like so:

**parent component:**

```html
<data-table-search v-bind="$attrs">
```

and now you don't need to declare all of those props in the parent component.